# Dúvida com Javascript Replace

Tags: javascript

**Minha situação**: Possuo um input mascarado dessa forma: `0,0000 %`. Porém, para conseguir validar como desejo, preciso utilizar um `replace`, trocando a vírgula por ponto, removendo o `%` e então tratando o valor desta forma: `0.0000`.

Sei que posso utilizar algo como `numero.replace(",",".")` mas isso só irá trocar a vírgula pelo ponto, e minha validação continuará falhando.

É possível num só `replace`ou código similar, trocar os caracteres e remover o `%`?

**Apesar do problema já ter sido solucionado, abaixo está a minha resposta ao Sergio**:

Na minha validação, posso ter números somente menores ou iguais a 100. Quanto ao formato (string ou number), não sei afirmar com 100% de certeza. Creio que terá que ser *number*, pois provavelmente este valor será guardado num BD e como string acho que não será muito viável.

**Detalhe**: Não é recomendável que eu use nada *back-end* por enquanto. Somente *front-end*. É mais uma validação client side para não deixar o usuário enviar valores bizarros no post.

Comment: @Sergio aí está, amigo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível com expressão regular. Não sou mestre no assunto, mas isto parece dar conta:

```
var re = /^(\d+),(\d+) %$/;
console.log("0,0000 %".replace(re, "$1.$2"));
```

A expressão regular acima funciona assim:

- `^`: a partir do início da string
- `(\d+)`: deve existir um ou mais dígitos; os parênteses são para capturar o que casar com essa parte da expressão
- `,`: seguido de vírgula
- `(\d+)`: seguido de um ou mais dígitos (novamente capturados)
- `%`: seguido de espaço e sinal da porcentagem
- `$`: fim da string (ou seja, nada após a porcentagem)

Na segunda parte do `replace`, os dois grupos capturados com parênteses são referenciados como `$1` e `$2` respectivamente. Ou seja, `$1` são os dígitos antes da vírgula, e `$2` são os que vêm depois dela. Montamos uma nova string com esses dois termos, e `.` no meio em vez de `,`.

---

Considerando sua edição, essa expressão parece insuficiente, pois permite qualquer número, mesmo que maior que 100 (exceto negativos, que você não mencionou mas estou considerando inválidos). Uma expressão mais precisa:

```
/^(\d{1,2}|100),(\d+) %$/
```

A parte nova, `(\d{1,2}|100)`, significa que antes da vírgula deve haver dois dígitos quaisquer, ou o valor `"100"`.

Comment: Ótimo @bfavaretto! Matou a questão de forma simples! Obrigado!

Ficaria agradecido se pudesse explicar o que o código acima faz exatamente. Valendo um upvote... rs

Comment: Realmente eu devia ter explicado (não só pelo upvote, hehe!). Estou correndo agora, mais tarde complemento ok?

Comment: Sem problemas, valeu!

Comment: Pronto Victor, acrescentei a explicação e outra opção de expressão regular. Também gosto da sugestão do Sergio.

Comment: Obrigado, muito bem explicado! Apesar da nova correção, a antiga já não me permite sequer valores como `100,0001%`.

Comment: Ambas deveriam permitir isso sim, Victor. É porque ambas exigem um espaço antes do  `%`, como no seu exemplo. Mas você pode remover o espaço, ou usar `(\d+) ?%` para deixá-lo opcional.

Answer (score 2):

Fica mais uma sugestão para além da boa resposta do [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28520/129).

Uma vez que tem numeros relativamente pequenos pode usar o parseFloat para converter para Number. Assim basta trocar a `,` para o parseFloat conseguir trabalhar com o numero:

```
var string = '0,00123%';
var numero = parseFloat(string.replace(',', '.'));
console.log(numero); // 0.00123 
console.log(typeof numero); // number
```

#### Exemplo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/ksyk5ux1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var numero = '0,0000 %';
    alert(numero.split(',').join('.').split('%').join('').trim());
</script>
```

Se usar um split para quebrar a String e um join para unir, tendo algum caractere ou não como fim, consome menos processamento no browser e é mais rapido que usar uma expressão regular. Um trim no final para remover o espaço vazio.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ax7b2gr/